# Determine the matrix of the operator $T: M \mapsto AMB$ on the space $F^{2\times 2}$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone help me get started on this one:

Let $A$ and $B$ be $2 \times 2$ matrices. Determine the matrix of the operator $T: M \mapsto AMB$ on the
space $F^{2\times 2}$ of $2 \times 2$ matrices, with respect to the basis $(e_{11},e_{12},e_{21},e_{22})$ of $F^{2\times 2}$.

**UPDATE**: I completed the problem as suggested. Is this right?

$AMB =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}m_{11}b_{11} + a_{12}m_{21}b_{11} + a_{11}m_{12}b_{21} + a_{12}m_{22}b_{21} &
a_{11}m_{11}b_{12} + a_{12}m_{21}b_{12} + a_{11}m_{12}b_{22} + a_{12}m_{22}b_{22} \\
a_{21}m_{11}b_{11} + a_{22}m_{21}b_{11} + a_{21}m_{12}b_{21} + a_{22}m_{22}b_{21} &
a_{21}m_{11}b_{12} + a_{22}m_{21}b_{12} + a_{21}m_{12}b_{22} + a_{22}m_{22}b_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$T(e_{11}) =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}b_{11} &
a_{11}b_{12} \\
a_{21}b_{11} &
a_{21}b_{12} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$T(e_{12}) =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}b_{21} &
a_{11}b_{22} \\
a_{21}b_{21} &
a_{21}b_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$T(e_{21}) =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{12}b_{11} &
a_{12}b_{12} \\
a_{22}b_{11} &
a_{22}b_{12} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

$T(e_{22}) =
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{12}b_{21} &
a_{12}b_{22} \\
a_{22}b_{21} &
a_{22}b_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}$

Converting to the given basis and building the linear operator matrix yields:

$
T = \begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}b_{11} & a_{11}b_{21} & a_{12}b_{11} & a_{12}b_{21} \\
 a_{11}b_{12} & a_{11}b_{22} & a_{12}b_{12} & a_{12}b_{22} \\
 a_{21}b_{11} & a_{21}b_{21} & a_{22}b_{11} & a_{22}b_{21} \\
 a_{21}b_{12} & a_{21}b_{22} & a_{22}b_{12} & a_{22}b_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

Comment: Looks good; I didn't check every last index, but you have exactly the right approach now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $M$, you can write $M = m_{11}e_{11} + m_{12}e_{12} + \dots$, and similarly, if $C = AMB$, $C = c_{11}e_{11} + \dots$. It is from this viewpoint (i.e. a $2\times 2$ matrix as a $4\times 1$ vector) that we will write down the matrix of $T$. So, in particular, we're looking for a $4\times 4$ matrix.

Label the entries of $A$ and $B$ the same way. Now, write out the entire product $AMB$ in terms of the $m_{ij}, a_{ij}, b_{ij}$ (i.e. write a formula for each $c_{ij}$ in terms of the others). Do you see where to go from here?