# Let V= Mat2×2(K) be a 4-dimensional vector space with the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let V= Mat2×2(K) be a 4-dimensional vector space with the basis:
v1=[1   0; 0   0],   v2=[0   1; 0   0],   v3=[0   0; 1   0],   v4=[0   0; 0   1].
Let A=[a   b; c   d] ∈ Mat2×2(K). We define the linear map T:V→V, M→A·M, for M∈V.Find  the  matrix  associated  with T with  respect  to  the  standard  basis.

My attempt:
A*{v1 v2 v3 v4} to get a 2x8 matrix but i dont know where to go from here? 
i tried to put them together and got:
[a 0 b 0; c 0 d 0; 0 a 0 b; 0 c 0 d]
I have no idea if this is even correct?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use MathJax in your answer and show what you have done to solve the problem so far. Nobody likes a homework CTRL C - CTRL V.

Comment: Set $B=I$ in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1203607/determine-the-matrix-of-the-operator-t-m-mapsto-amb-on-the-space-f2-times).

Comment: what do i do with the v1 ... v4?

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the standard basis matrices $v_i$ to column vectors (just take the transpose of the row vectors you gave in the post), calculate each matrix product $A\cdot v_i$, and put the flattened result in the $i$th column.

Comment: A is 2x2 matrix and if i flatten the vi i get a 4x1 matrix. That multiplication is not possible?

Comment: Flattening is for *coordinating* only (in the standard basis), but $v_i$ keeps being a $2\times 2$ matrix.

Comment: sorry but i am confused on how the v1..v4 standard basis will be used

Comment: $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} =av_1+bv_2+cv_3+dv_4$ hence it is coordinated as $\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d} $ with respect to basis $v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$.

Comment: oh ok thank you so much for the clarification! really appreciate it. so then i would multiply that [a;b;c;d] by the Identity (4x4) matrix?

Comment: No. Both $A$ and $v_i$ are $2\times 2$ matrices, especially when you multiply them.